# Delphi 10.2 how to use the ZipProgress

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

An earlier StackOverflow topic provides some sample code for using the progress event while using `TZipFile`:

[Using Delphi Toyko creating a Zip file onprocess example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383554/)

I am able to make the example work if I use it as a MainForm. But I am completely stymied in trying to convert the code to work in a separate unit.

Every time I try to compile the code as a unit, I get an error message:

> E2009 Incompatible types: 'method pointer and regular procedure'

The error is triggered on the line:

```pascal
TZipFile.ZipDirectoryContents('C:\temp\Test.zip','c:\temp\zipTest',zcDeflate,OnZipProgressEvent);
```

I've researched in every way I could think of, and tried all manner of alternatives, but no luck.

Can anyone explain how to make the `OnZipProgressEvent` code work in a separate unit?

This is the unit code that I have so far:

```pascal
unit ZipDelphiNative; 

interface 

uses 
  Windows,SysUtils, StrUtils, Variants, MaskUtils, Dialogs,StdCtrls, 
  Graphics, Menus,Classes, ClipBrd,  System.Zip, Winapi.Messages, 
  System.Generics.Collections, system.ioutils,  system.types, 
  Forms,ComCtrls, DateUtils; 

Type 
  TZipProgressEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; FileName: string; Header: TZipHeader; Position: Int64) of object; 
  // TZipProgressEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; FileName: string; Header: TZipHeader; Position: Int64); 

function jrCreateZipFromFolder(inZipName : string; inSourcePath : string; inTargetPath : string) : boolean; 
procedure OnZipProgressEvent (Sender: TObject; FileName: string; Header: TZipHeader; Position: Int64); 

var 
  PreviousFilename : string; 

implementation 

uses
  Unit1; 

function jrCreateZipFromFolder(inZipName : string; inSourcePath : string; inTargetPath : string) : boolean; 
  //inTargetPath is already confirmed to be valid 
  //Zips all files in inSourcePath & subfolders 
var 
  Zip : TZipFile; 
  //  ZipCallBack: TZipProgressEvent; 
  sZipName, sSourceName : string; 
begin 
  result := true; 
  //  ZipCallBack :=  OnZipProgressEvent; 
  sZipName := IncludeTrailingBackslash(inTargetPath) + inZipName; 
  sSourceName := IncludeTrailingBackslash(inSourcePath) ; 
  Zip := TZipFile.Create; 
  try 
    if FileExists(sZipName) then 
      DeleteFile(sZipName); 

    //    zip.ZipDirectoryContents(sZipName, sSourceName, zcDeflate, ZipCallBack);  //do not store folder too 

    zip.ZipDirectoryContents(sZipName, sSourceName, zcDeflate, OnZipProgressEvent);  //do not store folder too 

    zip.Close; 

  except 
    result := false; 
  end; 
  FreeAndNil(Zip); 
end; 

procedure OnZipProgressEvent(Sender: TObject; FileName: string; 
  Header: TZipHeader; Position: Int64); 
begin 
  if PreviousFilename <> FileName then 
  begin 
    PreviousFilename := FileName; 
    unit1.Form1.ProgressBar1.Max := Header.UncompressedSize; 
    unit1.Form1.ProgressBar1.Position := Position; 
  end 
  else 
    //    Unit1.Form1.ProgressBar1.Position := (Position * 100) div Header.UncompressedSize ; 
    Unit1.Form1.ProgressBar1.Position := Position; 
  Application.ProcessMessages; 
end; 

end.
```

I have tried defining `TZipProgressEvent` with and without `of object`.  I have two options in this code for using the `TZipProgressEvent`, either like the original example, or the commented out version of defining `ZipCallBack`. Both work under different circumstances when used in a Form. Neither work when used in this unit.

So, I am baffled as to how to make this work. It would sure be nice if Embarcadero offered useful sample code!

Comment: Then my previous comment gives you the answer. The `OnZipProgressEvent` needs to be an object method, **not** a standalone procedure. Don't try to make your own declaration of the event.  Add the proper units to the uses clause, which will declare it for you, and then make the event handler a class method, not an independent procedure. It's declared as a `procedure of object`, which means it  needs to be an object method.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Unfortunately I have seen variations on this suggestion during my research and I have no idea how to accomplish this. That is why I'm seeking an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TZipProgressEvent` is declared as being `of object`, which means it must be a method of an object (class). So in order to implement it, you need to declare a class that implements that method with that signature (the signature in the `TZip` class, not the one you made up).

This should get you started. Add your own code to the implementation of `jrCreateZipFromFolder` and `TMyZipProgress.ShowZipProgress`, as I've said in the code comments below. I've made it a `class procedure` so that you don't have to create an instance of `TMyZipProgress` to use it.

```
unit ZipDelphiNative; 

interface

function jrCreateZipFromFolder(inZipName, inSourcePath, inTargetPath: string): Boolean;

implementation

{ TMyZip }

uses
  System.Zip;

type
  TMyZipProgress = class(TObject)
  private
    class procedure ShowZipProgress(Sender: TObject; FileName: string;
      Header: TZipHeader; Position: Int64);
  end;


function jrCreateZipFromFolder(inZipName, inSourcePath,
  inTargetPath: string): boolean;
var
  FZip: TZipFile;
begin
  Result := False;
  FZip := TZipFile.Create;
  try
    // Rest of your zip file code here, then call
    FZip.ZipDirectoryContents(sZipName, sSourceName, zcDeflate, TMyZipProgress.ShowZipProgess);
    Result := True;
  finally
    FZip.Free;
  end;
end;

class procedure TMyZipProgress.ShowZipProgress(Sender: TObject; FileName: string;
  Header: TZipHeader; Position: Int64);
begin
  // Show your progress here, whatever it needs to do
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This did the job nicely.